# Seems like Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Doesn't recognise NVIDIA Drivers

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, intel-graphics

I am a beginner in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Just last week I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have a dual boot machine on new Laptop with Secure boot switched-on (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.5).

I have NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 in my laptop, so i tried to install Nvidia drivers by following the steps mentioned here: [Installing GPU drivers for Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-gpu-installation-on-ubuntu-18-4-9b12230a1d31)

After performing the steps exactly the same, you can see that I have installed NVIDIA Driver :
[image: Installed Recommended Driver]

I have then rebooted and I can see that `nvidia-smi` runs perfectly fine *(earlier i would get error)*
[image: Output of nvidia-smi command]

Then I ran `sudo prime-select nvidia`
[image: Getting output that nvidia is already set]

[image]

Again, I rebooted
But still the Ubuntu Settings mention that I am using intel drivers.
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: @guiverc Yes I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Does the NVIDIA 455 Driver mess up with my Ubuntu Kernel?

Comment: @guiverc thanks for mentioning that, I will update the question. But I have friends who have installed NVIDIA Drivers using this method and are using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for data science.

Comment: I have same problem with freezing when I reboot the laptop .. did you face problem with freezing ?